# < is not working in a string with email

Tags: php

I am making a script that sends some individual emails to specific users, since I need authentication, I am using PEAR mail function and its working great, but when I a try to put in the from address the name and email of my enterprise, I get an error, so I was testing and testing and went back to baby steps where a very simple script showed me that something is wrong, but I don´t know if it is with PHP configuration, my script, my structure or what is happening. I the following code, I have in one variable the name, the second one is the email, and the third one appends both and adds the < > for the email, when I echo it, only the name appears, the  is not echoed and that same is what is happening in my pear script.

```
    <?php
    $var1 = "John";
    $var2 = "john@domain.com";
    echo $var12 = "$var1 $var2<br>"; // This one outputs name and email without the < >
    echo $var122 = "$var1 <$var2> <br>"; // This one only outputs the data of $var1
    ?>
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: This won't help us with your script - as `Name <email@address.com>` is valid for PEAR.  Though, when echoing, it won't display because of the answer below - it's an unknown tag - view the source or enclose in `<pre>` tags to view as it would be in text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from the script will include `<john@domain.com>`, but as this is an unknown tag, the browser will ignore it. You will have to change `<` and `>` to `&lt;`, and `&gt;` in your php code.

Comment: Terje and Jon, thank you very much for your help. So this means that even if it does not display in the browser as < > it will be run fine by pear? This is going to be run via a cronjob for sending the emails. Thank you again.

Comment: @user2255536  As the script is syntactically correct, it will do it's job. It does however generate incorrect output, and should be fixed as shown in my answer.